# Plesk Already in use NODEJS

Tags: node.js

I have this problem on my server using PLesk ,
Specs: Ubuntu 18.0.40.1 , Plesk

I tried to change the port to random numbers and the same results, says already in use.I would like to do the deploys well to be able to learn, I can try elsewhere but it is a priority to do it in plesk
Nodejs Config:

```
const app = express();

//CORS
const domainWhiteList = [process.env.ORIGIN1,process.env.ORIGIN2]


app.use(cors({
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        console.log(origin)
        if (!origin || domainWhiteList.includes(origin)) {
            return callback(null,origin)
        }
        return callback('Not allowed by CORS ' + origin)
        
    }
}));

//Uso de cookies
app.use(cookieParser());

//Activar JSON Body Leer
app.use(express.json());

//Api de Inicio de Sesion
app.use("/api/v1/auth", authRouter);

//Api Links
app.use("/api/v1/links", linkRouter)


//Port Default
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;


//App se ejecuta en este port
app.listen(PORT, () => {console.log("Server is running on port:"+ PORT + " http://localhost:"+ PORT)});
```

````
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::4657
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1740:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1788:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1876:7)
    at Function.listen (/var/www/vhosts/vexshe.fun/proyects.vexshe.fun/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:635:24)
    at file:///var/www/vhosts/vexshe.fun/proyects.vexshe.fun/index.js:47:5
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1767:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -98,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 4657
}

Node.js v19.6.0```

I try to deploy my proyect in plesk , i do it in render and works fine but in plesk doesnt work.
````